# Unable to Delete Class Using Eclipse Force.com IDE

Tags: apex, class, eclipse, delete

I have a few classes and matching test classes that Force.com says are deleted, but then counts those classes toward the test coverage minimum.

I changed the status of the classes to "Deleted" in the XML file in Eclipse and then deployed the changes. That should delete it, correct?

Here is [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzplI.png) to show you what I mean. This is the MySave class. As far as I can tell it should be gone. You'll notice there are two other Classes with zero coverage: scheduledCreateEventEngagements and scheduledCreateTaskEngagements. They have the same problem.

None of these classes show up in Salesforce when I view them in setup.

I have tried [larger batches of deletes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3wgS.png) and they fail as well due to there supposedly not being enough code coverage.

Every other trigger and class in SF has 100% code coverage.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have refreshed the sandbox and then recreated the Eclipse project as well. Still no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a reference elsewhere.

I used [this website to find all references](http://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2015/08/28/easy-way-to-find-all-apex-references-in-salesforce/) and I found out there was a VF page pulling the class.

I am sorry for the simple question, but I hope this helps others in the future.

Comment: Also be sure to look at scheduled jobs as that may cause this same problem.